# Can't upload file (pdf, jpg, etc)

Tags: php, upload

i want to create a form where I simply can upload pictures, pdf and doc. 
Therefore I created the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?op=editpress&save=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file" class="control-label">Neue Datei hochladen:</label>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</form>
```

The PHP-Code:

```
if($_GET['save'] == 1 AND isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $allowedExts = array("pdf","doc","docx","png","jpg","jpeg","gif");
    $allowedMimeTypes = array('application/msword','application/pdf','image/gif','image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png');
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if (in_array( $_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimeTypes ) AND (5000000 < $_FILES["file"]["size"]) AND (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "There was an error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {   
        if (file_exists("../media/presse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            unlink("../media/presse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);         
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../media/logo/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);               
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Here comes the errormessage";
}
```

I always get the "errormessage" from the end of the script, when I try to upload a jpg or pdf. 
I have tried a lot of things, but nothing was the solutions for the error.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`5000000 < $_FILES["file"]["size"]` is your problem. You're testing "IF FILESIZE IS GREATER THAN 5000000 BYTES"

Also, `unlink("../media/presse/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);` is not very smart. Instead, you should generate a random string and append it between the file `name` and `extension`, then upload.

Comment: Hi Rob W,
thanks! I haven't seen that ..., thanks for the hint! Now everything works fine.